# How to store a file line by line into numpy.ndarray (Python)

Tags: python, numpy

I have to import a file, which for example contains 3 rows of numbers:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

How can I store them into a `numpy.ndarray M`, so that for example `M[0]` gives a `np.array` containing the first row, i.e. `[1,2,3,4]`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
import numpy as np


with open('test_file.txt') as file:
    arr = np.array(
        [
            np.array([float(num) for num in line.strip().split("\t")])
            for line in file
        ]
    )
print(arr)
```

and the array should look like the one below:

```
[array([1., 2., 3., 4.]) array([1., 2., 3.])
 array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.])]
```

Comment: Thank you, but i would have an array instead of a list, for each row.

Comment: @Wil  Oh I missed that. Please see the updated answer

Comment: Thank you @Giorgos. Since my row is `'13.8\t21.6\t28.9\t34.3\t38.2\t42\t44.6\t46.3\t47.4\t48.2\t47.4\t45.5\t\n'`, I put `'\t'` instead of `" "` in `split()`. But it gives me `ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''`. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: @Wil Looks like there are whitespaces? See my updated answer again

Answer (score 0):

Same as Giorgios but with a np.array instead of a list for rows :

```
import numpy as np


with open('test_file.txt') as file:
    arr = np.array(
        [
            np.array([float(num) for num in line.split(" ")])
            for line in file
        ]
    )
print(arr)
```

Comment: I would rather make a comment under Giorgios post, I feel like your post isn't sufficiently different to actually constitute answer on its own.

Comment: I agree but it seems below "50 reputations" we are not able to post a comment under others answers than ours.